# How to find operator with Fibonacci eigenvalues?

Tags: operator-theory, differential-operators

How can I find the operator that satisfies this equation?

$$F_nx^n=Dx^n$$

Summing over $n$ we can rewrite this as $$\frac1{1-x-x^2}=D\frac1{1-x}$$
I am unsure whether this can be solved.

---

I am trying to solve it in a similar way to something like this:
$$nx^n=Dx^n$$ has solution $$D=x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$$
I am not sure really how else to describe it. Other than the fact that $D$ can't really depend on $n$ which might make this equation unsolvable.

Comment: operator on what space? You assume continuity of $D$

Comment: @user159517 I am not sure what you mean

Comment: That second is *not* equivalent to the first. It is necessary, but not sufficient. As an example, there are operators with $D\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-x}$ without it being true that $Dx^n=x^n$. For example: $(Df)(x) = f(0)+xf(x)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's a good point. Part of the problem is that I have no idea what I should be reading in order to solve such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression): 
$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\varphi^n-\psi^n\right)$$

where $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\psi = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Then $$(Df)(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(f(\varphi x)-f(\psi x)\right)$$

If you write the scaling operators $(S_\alpha f)(x)=f(\alpha x)$, then you can write the above as:

$$D=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(S_\phi-S_\psi\right)$$

I suspect there is no closed form in terms of just $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $x$.

Note that the $S_\alpha$ have the following properties:

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}S_\alpha &= \alpha S_\alpha \frac{d}{dx}\\
S_\alpha S_\beta &= S_{\alpha\beta}\\
xS_\alpha &= \frac{1}\alpha(S_\alpha x)\end{align}$$

Comment: Is $\phi=-1/\varphi$?

Comment: $\psi=-1/\varphi$. I'm using the symbols on the Wikipedia page for Binet's formula. Not sure what you mean by $\phi$, which is a different form of the letter $\varphi.$  @AliCaglayan

Comment: Yes sorry, that was a latex blunder. I mean psi.

Comment: I didn't make my question very clear I am sorry about this. I have amended my question now.

Comment: If we have a scaling operator, can't we decompose it in terms of $x$ and $\frac{d}{dx}$ through Taylor's formula, as done by Daniel?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: There are (at least) two ways of indexing the Fibonacci series.  Below I work with the $F_0 = F_1 = 1$ convention rather than the $F_0 = 0, F_1 = F_2 = 1$ convention.

---

I assume you want $D$ to be a differential operator, given the tags.  Then we have

$$D = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty f_k(x) \frac{d^k}{dx^k}$$

for some functions $f_k(x)$, and we want

$$F_n x^n = D x^n = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty f_k(x) \frac{d^k}{dx^k} x^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n (n \; P \; k) \; f_k(x) \; x^{n-k}$$

Let's suppose $f_k(x) = c_k x^k$ for some constant $c_k$, making this say

$$F_n x^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n (n \; P \; k) c_k x^n$$

or just

$$F_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n (n \; P \; k) c_k = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} c_k$$

This gives a recursive definition of the $c_k$.  Now if we find the first few $c_k$ we see that they're fractions with denominators that look like k!, so let's try defining $a_k := k! c_k$ so that our expression becomes

$$F_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!} k! c_k = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a_k$$

Calculating the first several $a_k$ we see that they are
$$1, 0, 1, -1, 2, -3, 5, -8, 13, -21, \ldots$$
To me, that looks like $a_0 = 1$ and $a_k = (-1)^k F_{k-2}$ for $k > 0$.  I imagine you can check this actually works using Pascal's identity or something, though I didn't actually check it.  This would then give the formula
$$D = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k F_{k-2}}{k!} \; x^k \; \frac{d^k}{dx^k},$$
at least assuming I got all the indices correct.

Comment: I can confirm your equality $F_n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dbinom{n}{k} \left(-1\right)^k F_{k-2}$ (where the Fibonacci sequence is extended to the negative indices by following its recursive definition backwards, so that $F_{-1} = 0$ and $F_{-2} = 1$). Indeed, this follows easily from the Binet formula. Nice observation!